# Is there way in Shopify to categorize "Collections" in lists?

Tags: collections, tags, shopify, product, liquid

Say I want to show 2 different collection lists(just the titles with links to their relative pages) on 2 different pages in Shopify; is there a way in Shopify that can be done?  As far as I can see, either I show all "Collections" on a page or none at all. Is there no option to categorize them so that I can use liquid to only show certain collections?

The only other option to this I found is to hard code those collection menus on the page. But the issue with that is, any new collection I create, I will have to manually add it in to the code if I want to show it.

Comment: cant exactly understant what you want. But if you want to show different types of content for different collections, you can create templates and assign them accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

If you want to display all collections after a certain collection, once you find that handle, just have it parse the rest of them after it finds the handle.

Sorry my liquid is a little rusty so this is pseudo code.

```
{{ liquidtempvar = 0 }}

{% loop through collections %}

{% if thiscollection.handle == 'firstcollectioniwanttodisplay' %}

{{ liquidtempvar = 1 }}

{% endif %}

{% if liquidtempvar eq 1 %}

{{ loop through this collection and every collection after }}

<a href="{{collection.product.url}}">{{ collection.product.handle }}</a>

{{ endloop }}

{% endif %}

{{ endloop }}
```

Something like that...

**END UPDATE**

If you want to display a list of the items in a collection as links, then you would need to parse the collections object in the template of the page where you want to display them.

You would want to use the collection [handle](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/basics/handle) to qualify/filter which collections you wanted to display.

Using liquid loop over each collection, if the handle matches the collection you want,  loop over the collection and display the links.

If you are looking to do this as a menu through the navigation, I think you can probably do it using query strings in the URL.

```
collection.next_product
```

and

```
collection.prev_product
```

will return the URL of the next and previous products in the collection.

[Collection Navigation](https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/collections/how-to-navigate-within-a-collection)

[Collection Object Reference](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/collection)

Comment: You are correct on your first guess. I see that I can that it can be done with collection handle.  Now my question is, if I want to add a newly created collection to the list, is there way other than adding that collection manually into the code?

Comment: You would need to add it to your code unless you put all of the new collections and any collections you wanted displayed at the end of your list of collections.  Then you could search for the handle of the first one, and then just have it parse out every collection after that.   Another option would be to build a private app for your store, which isn't as hard as you might think.

Comment: That answers my question.  Thank you!